# jquery multiple autocomplete with json

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am working on jquery multiple autocomplete, however, while i type something, all the items are published instead of the matching ones. My Javascript is

```
$('.tags').bind("keydown", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
}).autocomplete({
    source : function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON($.cookie('base_url') + "js/getaddressbook.php", {
            term : extractLast(request.term)
        }, response);
    },
    search : function() {
        var term = extractLast(this.value);
        if (term.length < 2) {
            return false;
        }
    },

    focus : function() {
        return false;
    },
    select : function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        terms.pop();
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join("; ");
        return false;
    }
});
```

The js/getaddressbook.php returns

> ["gunjan.soni","askhr","saurabh.burman","Aditi.Nehra","ithelpdesk","shipra.kwatra","gagandeep.manchanda"]

Not sure where am i going wrong.

Below is the snapshot how it looks like

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmRjX.png]

Please help!

My JS controller has the function

```
Public function getaddressbook() {
        $this -> load -> model('common_model');
        $data = $this -> common_model -> addressbook();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

And the common_model has the function

```
Public function addressbook()
    {
        $this -> db -> select('emailid');
        $this -> db ->where('emailid <>','');
        $result = $this -> db -> get('addressbook');
        if ($result -> num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach ($result->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row -> emailid;
            }
            return ($data);
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: seems like the trouble might be in the getaddressbook.php logic. can you share some of that code?

Comment: Sorry Adunahay, i have edited my question and put the code in...

Comment: no problem. I think the answer from mallix is on the right track!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the **term** anywhere in your controller.

And of course using that term to query your database for example:

```
$this->db->like('column_name', $term);
```

For your code, it could be:

```
Public function getaddressbook() {
        $this -> load -> model('common_model');
        $term = $this->input->get('term');
        $data = $this->common_model->addressbook($term);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

Public function addressbook($term)
    {
        $this -> db -> select('emailid');
        $this -> db ->where('emailid <>','');
        $this->db->like('column_name', $term);
        $result = $this -> db -> get('addressbook');
        if ($result -> num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach ($result->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row -> emailid;
            }
            return ($data);
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If its post then use: $this-input->post('term'); else use $this->input->get('term'). Depends on your autocomplete js. Your code indicates a get method, see $.getJSON

Comment: Hey Thanks Mallix, that worked like a charm. :) however, i am not able to get multiple autocomplete now :( not sure where am i going wrong.

Comment: That is another question I guess.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with this.value = terms.join("; ") as i put a "," it works perfect.

Comment: oh Yes, i do! but please mallix help me with one more thing, how can  i get it work with a semicolon instead of a comma.

Comment: Post a new question for this. Because I really don t understand what exactly you are trying to do by "multiple autocomplete".